# How can I set up the same prices in the Apple App Store and Google Play Store?

Tags: google-play, in-app-purchase, app-store

I want to set up prices for consumable and non-consumable in-app products in the Apple App Store and Google Play Store, but the prices are not the same in USD. I set the price in both stores to 2,29 EUR and the price is indeed the same when I purchase the in-app product in my iOS and Android application. But in USD, the Apple shows me 1,99 USD in my developer account and Google shows me 2,49 USD in Google Play Console. I have not tested if the USD prices are the same if you purchase the product in my application.

[Apple Price in USD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAxCO.png)

[Google Price in USD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvgK6.png)

Why are the Google and Apple prices in USD not the same?

I have just compared EUR and USD, I have not yet compared other currencies. But I want that prices in one currency(for example USD) are the same in the Apple App Store and Google Play Store.

What can I do so that the prices are the same in both stores?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS it won't allow us to manually set up the pricing. They have fix price tiers defined for all countries & they won't keep changing frequently as per the current price trends. So for ex. if Tier 1 as per US currency they set up fix 0.99$. That is fix rate for the tier 1 & will not change.

Where as in Android version it allows you to Add pricing manually. More importantly it allows to add currency in your country's currency. So for ex. If you are from USA it will ask you to enter in USD. But you can change pricing for the other countries as well as it allows to edit the currency for the other countries.

> So basically in iOS its more structured & controlled by the Apple it
>   self regarding the price ranges & Price tiers. Where as Android allows
>   you a freedom to choose prices of your own.

So in that case its very hard, almost impossible to manage the same price tiers for the both. You can try manage as nearest but it won't be accurate all the time.

Hope this will help everyone.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should use "Price includes applicable tax" or "Add applicable tax on top of price" in Google Play Console. Is it better if I chose "Price includes applicable tax"?

Comment: @Hobbit7 yes bro choose the first option "Price includes applicable tax"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the above answer really answers the initial question.

The reason the pricing differs is Android will add tax to your starting price when it generates the prices for each territory, where as the App Store does not add any tax onto the price, and will just convert your price into the native currency.

It seems you can turn this behaviour off in the Play Store if you want. However, it seems very logical behaviour when compared to the App Store, which allows you to set a price, then the territory tax rate comes out of the price. So you end up subsidising users in countries with tax and making inconsistent proceeds depending on where the customer is based, unless you manually override the price in each territory with tax.

If anyone from Apple ever reads this, please add an option to bump the prices according to local tax. Plz and thanks