# Automatically add tax to app store pricing

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I might be missing something here, but is there a way to automatically add expected tax to the starting price of of a product on the app store without manually going through it?

Play store seems to do this automatically which is nice. Seems like I need to go through each product then region, adding it manually so the prices on the Play Store mirror the app store.

For example, base price of $20 (19.38 euros).

For EU countries, VAT is 20%, so the price should be 23.26 euros, let's say 23 euros, but Apple's automatic pricing will just convert $20 to euros without factoring in the different tax rates.

FYI while I do want Play Store prices to mirror App Store as per this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56816186/how-can-i-set-up-the-same-prices-in-the-apple-app-store-and-google-play-store), that is not the purpose of this ticket. The purpose of this ticket is find out how to make the adjustment to App Store prices without having to do it manually territory by territory.

Thanks

Comment: Where are you seeing the price? In the app? In the AppStore? Is it for the purchase price of the app? Or a subscription? Or an in app purchase? Or is it when selecting the price in AppStore Connect?

Comment: AFAIK the prices in the App Store pricing table include the relevant sales taxes for the country. So €20 would be inclusive of the 20% VAT. So the price is €16 plus 20% VAT = €20

Comment: Hi @fogmeister, this is the price in app store connect under subscription prices > starting price then view all territories by price.

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/26815. Your proceeds on a €20 IAP would be either €14.16 or €11.66 depending on whether you pay Apple15% or 30%

Comment: @paulw11 understand that, but that means a) I would need to adjust all play store pricing to match otherwise i'm charging Android users in tax territories unfairly b) i'm making inconsistent proceeds depending where the customer is located, which also feels unfair on some users as would need to raise the prices globally to account.

Comment: I have never set up purchases on the play store, but can't you just set the price you want the user to pay inclusive of sales tax? If not then it seems the issue is with Google.

Comment: Looking at the comments on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56816186/how-can-i-set-up-the-same-prices-in-the-apple-app-store-and-google-play-store) play store has a "price includes applicable tax" option. Use that and set the play store price to the same value as the Apple price tier.

Comment: Hi @paulw11 appreciate the help here, but not quite getting the solution I was after. Yes, I could adjust my play store pricing, but I much prefer the way the play store has generated the prices. It means consistent proceeds regardless of the user territory. Seems the only way to address this the to manually update prices on the app store to account for local taxes.